# How to stop service in spring batch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-job-monitoring

Follow the title, i have a service running in backend using spring batch.
My service:

```
@Service
publlic class TestBatch {
public void testDelay(String jobID) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            for(int i=0; i< 1000; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(jobID + " is running");
            }
           
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My tasklet:

```
public class TestTasklet implement Tasklet {

@Resource
    private TestBatch testBatch ;

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {        
        testBatch.testDelay("Test01"); // Param to show in cololog
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

I'm try to stop job:

```
@Service
public class JobService {

    @Autowired
    private SimpleJobOperator simpleJobOperator;

    @Autowired
    private JobExplorer jobs;

    public void stopJob(String jobid) {
        simpleJobOperator.stop(jobid);// Using job operator

        JobExecution jobExecution = jobs.getJobExecution(jobid); // Using job execution
        jobExecution.stop();
    }
}
```

Job is stop, but in my console still output text:

```
Test01 is running
Test01 is running
Test01 is running
...
```

I don't know how to stop `TestBatch` - method `testDelay()` when job stop. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [StoppableTasklet](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/StoppableTasklet.html) and not `Tasklet`. Spring Batch will call `StoppableTasklet#stop` when the job is requested to stop through the `JobOperator`.

However, it is up to you to make sure your code stops correctly, here is an excerpt from the Javadoc:

```
It is up to each implementation as to how the stop will behave.
The only guarantee provided by the framework is that a call to JobOperator.stop(long)
will attempt to call the stop method on any currently running StoppableTasklet.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. In my case, im running job 2 times. Each job calling `testDelay()` method. After i try to stop job, message still output. I just want to stop 1 job and 1 job still running and output message.